# Need a recorder that can record my mouse and take away the background image when i do so

Tags: display, mouse

I need it for some animations I am doing: the software must record the mouse and must let me take the background image afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is what you are looking for.
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Others/IOGraph.shtml
It records your mouse with a white background.
If you want to set a custom background image, you can use Photoshop/GIMP to remove the background.